# I have problem understanding the condition of the following while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, assignment-operator, strcpy

```
void strcpy(char *s, char *t)
{
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while ((*s = *t) != '\0') {
        s++;
        t++;
    }
}
```

I made a function to copy string `t` to string `s` using pointers from K&R.
The while loop uses `(*s = *t)!='\0'`
which is supposed to mean that to run loop till the we reach the end of `t` string
but I didn't understand how it works,
According to me: when the end is reached `s` gets `'\0'` in end so it got assigned but how the comparision of this is made with `!='\0'` part, does the bracket `(*s=*t)` returned `'\0'` in end and then it is compared and the loop is ended?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does "while(\*s++ = \*t++)" copy a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810129/how-does-whiles-t-copy-a-string)

Comment: `i` is never used in your code.

Comment: "when the end is reached s gets '\0' in end" Close, but wrong. No, `s` will not become `NULL` but `*s` will be a 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the line

```
if ( ( a = b ) != c )
```

is equivalent to the following:

```
a = b;
if ( a != c )
```

This is because the sub-expression `( a = b )` evaluates to the new value of `a`.

For the same reason, in the line

```
while ((*s = *t) != '\0')
```

the sub-expression `( *s = *t )` will evaluate to the new value of `*s`, so the loop condition is effectively `*s != '\0'`, where `*s` is the new value, which is the value of `*t`.

So yes, you are correct that the loop will end as soon as `*t` becomes a null character.

Answer (score 0):

It can be written in the shorter form. The function should also return something.

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char * restrict src)
{
    char *wrk = dest;
    while ((*wrk++ = *dest++));
    return dest;
}
```