# open() in Python does not create a file if it doesn't exist

Tags: python, linux, file-io, file-permissions

What is the best way to open a file as read/write if it exists, or if it does not, then create it and open it as read/write? From what I read, `file = open('myfile.dat', 'rw')` should do this, right?

It is not working for me (Python 2.6.2) and I'm wondering if it is a version problem, or not supposed to work like that or what.

The enclosing directory was writeable by user and group, not other (I'm on a Linux system... so permissions 775 in other words), and the exact error was:

```
IOError: no such file or directory.
```

Comment: As S.Mark mentioned, this should "just work". Is the enclosing directory writeable?

Comment: muksie's answer below worked (and baloo's too for that matter), but just for completeness, the enclosing dir was writable by user and group, not other (im on a linux system... so permissions 775 in other words), and the exact error was IOError: no such file or directory. thanks for the help guys.

Comment: make sure all the leading **folders** of the `file` exists.

Comment: for me the python `open(path/filename, mode='w+')` did not work until I created the target folder was created/existed `path_2_ziplike.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) `

Answer (score 1108, accepted):

You should use `open` with the `w+` mode:

```
file = open('myfile.dat', 'w+')
```

Comment: `w` truncates existing file. docs: *Modes `'r+'`, `'w+'` and `'a+'` open the file for updating (note that `'w+'` truncates the file).*

Comment: this did the trick. thank you. i feel like an idiot now for not reading the spec. i dont think 'rw' is even acceptable there. i must have been thinking of something else.

Comment: Note that a+ creates a file if it does not exist and, crucially, seeks the file to the end. So if you do a read immediately after opening this way, you'll get nothing. You need to seek back to the beginning first: f.seek(0)

Comment: [For the verbose, example-less documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: This is not the solution. The **problem is the directory**. Either the script lacks the permissions to create a file in that directory, or the directory simply doesn't exist. `open('myfile.dat', 'w')` is then enough.

Comment: If the path is pointing at a directory, make sure that directory exists: i.e. `(file = open('dir/myfile.dat', 'w+') )`, make sure the `dir` folder, aka directory exists; Python won't create that for you

Comment: This is not the solution. @TheRedPea: the OP said that the directory indeed did exist, but had 775 permissions ('o-w'), hence they couldn't write it.

Comment: Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError... This does no work

Comment: @ishandutta2007 well, if everyone disagreed with the answer, they would downvote it.

Comment: for me the python `open(path/filename, mode='w+')` did not work until I created the target folder was created/existed `path_2_ziplike.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) `

Comment: @DanielF is right. My testing shows that `w+` is not necessary for the file to be created if not existent already. `w` works if the directory is there.

Comment: w creates the file if it doesn't exist, the problem was in the directory

Answer (score 203):

The advantage of the following approach is that the file is **properly closed** at the block's end, even if an exception is raised on the way. It's equivalent to `try-finally`, but much shorter.

```
with open("file.txt","a+") as f:
    f.write("Hello world!")
    f.seek(4)
    f.readline()
    ...
```

> **a+** Opens a file for both appending and reading. The file pointer is
> at the end of the file if the file exists. The file opens in the
> append mode. If the file does not exist, it creates a new file for
> reading and writing. -[Python file modes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)

[seek() method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm) sets the file's current position.

e.g. `f.seek(4, 0)` with file content "Hello world!" would `f.readline()` "o world!"

```
f.seek(pos [, (0|1|2)])
pos .. Number. Position of the r/w pointer
[] .. optionally
() .. one of ->
  0 .. absolute position (default)
  1 .. relative position to current
  2 .. relative position from end
```

> Only "rwab+" characters are allowed; there must be exactly one of "rwa" - see Stack Overflow question *[Python file modes detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/656289/985454)*.

Comment: I try this with open(filename, 'a+') as myfile: and get IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: - why it doesn't create the file?

Comment: @Loretta Have you checked the value of `filename`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It is a unicode string. I also tried with open('{}.txt'.format(filename), 'a+') as myfile:

Comment: I am not using a path. and I tried open('test.txt', 'a+') it gets following exception 'TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found' in the line if os.stat(myfile).st_size == 0:

Comment: You need to properly define encoding for this to work. http://stackoverflow.com/q/728891/3701431

Comment: I have the same problem as Loretta.  I try `with open(self.save_to_filepath, 'a+') as f:` and it gives "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory".  The filepath is not in Unicode, either.

Comment: It turns out I was using the wrong directory path- I had been running the script from 2 different current directory locations.  So I used the workaround in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python and it worked fine.

Comment: for me the python `open(path/filename, mode='w+')` did not work until I created the target folder was created/existed `path_2_ziplike.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) `

Answer (score 65):

```py
'''
w  write mode
r  read mode
a  append mode

w+  create file if it doesn't exist and open it in write mode
r+  open for reading and writing. Does not create file.
a+  create file if it doesn't exist and open it in append mode
'''
```

Assuming that you are in working directory of the file.

Example:

```py
file_name = 'my_file.txt'
f = open(file_name, 'w+')  # open file in write mode
f.write('python rules')
f.close()
```

[FYI am using Python version 3.6.2]

Comment: Mode "w+" has the disadvantage of truncating the file, if it already exists. In many cases, this is NOT what people may want.

Answer (score 44):

Good practice is to use the following:

```
import os

writepath = 'some/path/to/file.txt'

mode = 'a' if os.path.exists(writepath) else 'w'
with open(writepath, mode) as f:
    f.write('Hello, world!\n')
```

Comment: It is bad to test a file before opening it, as it can lead to race conditions (file is deleted before it is opened). Race conditions can sometimes be used to exploit vulnerabilities in a system. "a+" mode is the best way to open the file: it creates a new file, and appends to existing files. Do not forget to wrap this in a try/except.

Comment: computing mode write or append has no interest. If file doesn't exist, append mode creates it.

Answer (score 38):

Since python 3.4 you *should* use `pathlib` to "touch" files.
It is a much more elegant solution than the proposed ones in this thread.

```
from pathlib import Path

filename = Path('myfile.txt')
filename.touch(exist_ok=True)  # will create file, if it exists will do nothing
file = open(filename)
```

Same thing with directories:

```
filename.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: `touch` does update the last modified time when used.

Comment: @DavidParks good point, just tested it and it is indeed true on ext4 file system and python3.7.2. I don't think that's intended or desired behaviour, maybe it's a bug wtih python?

Comment: Same thing when using `touch` at the command line in linux, so I assume it's intended behavior.

Comment: This introduces a race condition.

Comment: @Tordek how? I don't thinks that's true.

Comment: @Granitosaurus the file might still be deleted by some other process right after you touched it

Answer (score 34):

Change "rw" to "w+"

Or use 'a+' for appending (not erasing existing content)

Answer (score 28):

```
>>> import os
>>> if os.path.exists("myfile.dat"):
...     f = file("myfile.dat", "r+")
... else:
...     f = file("myfile.dat", "w")
```

`r+` means read/write.

Comment: This is Unpythonic. Rather than [checking if the file exists first](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl), one should [assume it does first, then handle the case that it doesn't](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp).

Comment: even worse, this code is prone to a race condition. thus, after checking if the file exists, the process could be interrupted and another process could create this file.

Comment: You would also need the "w+" flag so both files will be in a read and write modes.

Answer (score 17):

For Python 3+, I will do:

```py
import os

os.makedirs('path/to/the/directory', exist_ok=True)

with open('path/to/the/directory/filename', 'w') as f:
    f.write(...)
```

So, the problem is `with open` cannot create a file before the target directory exists. We need to create it and then `w` mode is enough in this case.

Comment: CAREFUL about this! It will truncate the content if the file exists.

Comment: Hi @NONONONONO, yes, it is what `w` mode does. If you want to keep the existing content, you can use `a` append mode. Refer to [open() doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Answer (score 13):

Use:

```
import os

f_loc = r"C:\Users\Russell\Desktop\myfile.dat"

# Create the file if it does not exist
if not os.path.exists(f_loc):
    open(f_loc, 'w').close()

# Open the file for appending and reading
with open(f_loc, 'a+') as f:
    #Do stuff
```

Note: Files have to be closed after you open them, and the [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) context manager is a nice way of letting Python take care of this for you.

Answer (score 11):

My answer:

```
file_path = 'myfile.dat'
try:
    fp = open(file_path)
except IOError:
    # If not exists, create the file
    fp = open(file_path, 'w+')
```

Answer (score 8):

`open('myfile.dat', 'a')` works for me, just fine.

in py3k your code raises `ValueError`:

```
>>> open('myfile.dat', 'rw')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    open('myfile.dat', 'rw')
ValueError: must have exactly one of read/write/append mode
```

in python-2.6 it raises `IOError`.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's `r+`, not `rw`. I'm just a starter, and that's what I've seen in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

What do you want to do with file? Only writing to it or both read and write?

`'w'`, `'a'` will allow write and will create the file if it doesn't exist.

If you need to read from a file, the file has to be exist before open it. You can test its existence before opening it or use a try/except.

Comment: Testing for existence before opening might introduce a race condition. Probably not a big deal in this case, but something to keep in mind.

Comment: "If you need to read from a file, the file has to be exist before you open it." Thank you for saving my sanity.

Answer (score 4):

Put w+ for writing the file, truncating if it exist, r+ to read the file, creating one if it don't exist but not writing (and returning null) or a+ for creating a new file or appending to a existing one.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to open it to read and write, I'm assuming you don't want to truncate it as you open it and you want to be able to read the file right after opening it. So this is the solution I'm using:

```
file = open('myfile.dat', 'a+')
file.seek(0, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

So You want to write data to a file, but only if it doesn’t already exist?.

This problem is easily solved by using the little-known x mode to open() instead of the usual w mode. For example:

```
 >>> with open('somefile', 'wt') as f:
 ...     f.write('Hello\n')
...
>>> with open('somefile', 'xt') as f:
...     f.write('Hello\n')
...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'somefile'
  >>>
```

If the file is binary mode, use mode xb instead of xt.

Answer (score 0):

I write this function from combination of above answers. you can use this before read and write to create file and it's parent dir. then use it if you want else close it:

```
import os
import ntpath

def open_even_not_exists(filepath, mode='w+'):
    if not ntpath.isdir(ntpath.dirname(filepath)):
        os.mkdir(ntpath.dirname(filepath))
    if not ntpath.exists(filepath):
        open(filepath, 'w+').close()
    return open(filepath, mode)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   f = open_even_not_exists('file.txt')
   # Do Stuff...
   f.close()
```

**notice: this worked in my project.You can don't return anything but becareful about close when you copy this function.*

Answer (score -3):

```
import os, platform
os.chdir('c:\\Users\\MS\\Desktop')

try :
    file = open("Learn Python.txt","a")
    print('this file is exist')
except:
    print('this file is not exist')
file.write('\n''Hello Ashok')

fhead = open('Learn Python.txt')

for line in fhead:

    words = line.split()
print(words)
```