# Checking file if exist then append record

Tags: python

I am creating a log file with line by line records.

1- If file does not exist, it should create file and append header row and the record
2- if it exists, check the text `timeStamp` in first line. If it exist then append the record otherwise add header columns and record itself

I tried both w,a and r+; nothing worked for me. Below is my code:

```
logFile = open('Dump.log', 'r+')
datalogFile = log.readline()
if 'Timestamp' in datalogFile:
    logFile.write('%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t\n'%(timestamp,logread,logwrite,log_skipped_noweight))
    logFile.flush()
else:
    logFile.write('Timestamp\t#Read\t#Write\t#e\n')
    logFile.flush()
    logFile.write('%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t\n'%(timestamp,logread,logwrite,log_skipped))
    logFile.flush()
```

Code fails if file don't exist

Comment: I can't see `logFile` being defined anywhere. Also, what is the error you get?

Comment: @mogambo fixed the typo. File not found error

Comment: you are opening the file without checking it exist or not.

Comment: Yeah but is there no switch that create file if don't exist and append date instead of overwrite everytime?

Comment: you can use append instead of read while opening the file.

Comment: Possibly duplicated question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967194/python-open-does-not-create-file-if-it-doesnt-exist).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `'a+'` mode:

```
logFile = open('Dump.log', 'a+')
```

description:

> **a+**
>   Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not
>   exist.  The stream is positioned at the end of the file.  Subsequent
>   writes to the file will always end up at the then current
>   end of file, irrespective of any intervening fseek(3) or similar

Answer (score 1):

Following code would work:

```
import os
f = open('myfile', 'ab+') #you can use a+ if it's not binary
f.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
print f.readline() #print the first line
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
if os.path.exists(my_file):
    print 'file does not exist'
    # some processing
else:
    print 'file exists'
    # some processing
```

Comment: I could definitely do it but I was wondering whether some file switch can do the trick?

Comment: @user3 I tried append switch but I need to read too before append. It is not reading at all

Comment: if file does not exist, `open` raises an `IOError` so apart from catching this exception, there is no way

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the file in `r+` mode which means you assume the file exists. Also, if you intend the write on the file, you should open it with `a+` mode (unashamedly stealing ndpu's explanation)
Your code would become:

```
    logFileDetails = []
    with open("Dump.log","a+") as logFile:
        logFileDetails = logFile.readLines()
        if logFileDetails and "Timestamp" in logFileDetails:
            pass # File exists, write your stuff here
        else:
            pass # Log file doesn't exist, write timestamp here
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking a file existence introduces a race condition, i.e. another process can create it or delete it **after** the check returns false or true, respectively, creating heavy bugs. You should instead use:

```
if open('path\to.filename', 'a+') != '':
  stuff_if_exists
else:
  stuff_if_not_exists
```