# Delete a file if it exists. If it doesn't, create it

Tags: python, file, error-handling, delete-file

Title says all.

My code:

```
 try:
        os.remove("NumPyResults.txt")

 except IOError:

        with open("NumPyResults.txt", 'a') as results_file:
            outfile = csv.writer(results_file)
            outfile.writerow(.......)
```

The reason it is in append is because it is in a function and called numerous times.  So I want a new file every time I run the program, by deleting the old one and writing the new one.

However this does not create a new file.  I also created the file in the directory I am running from and it doesn't delete it either.

I get

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'NumPyResults.txt'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967194/open-in-python-does-not-create-a-file-if-it-doesnt-exist

Comment: `append` doesn't remove the file by definition

Comment: Why not just use `open(path, 'w')`? It deletes the old file and rewrites over it.

Comment: All this is inside a function? Won't the file get deleted each time you make a call?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The exception I get for a missing filename is 'OSError', not 'IOError'.
And if you get the exception, you just want to pass, and the file writing should be outside the try block.

```
try:
    os.remove("NumPyResults.txt")
except OSError:
    pass

with open("NumPyResults.txt", 'a') as results_file:
    results_file.write('hi\n')
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I get `FileNotFoundError` on python3.4 and `OSError` on python2.7