# Why does using open(filename) fail with "'filename' is not defined"?

Tags: python, file-io, nameerror

I want to open a text file containing a column of words and create a list or, alternatively, a string containing these words.

Why do I get this error:

```
>>> with open(some_file.txt, 'r') as some_file:
...    some_list = [_ for _ in some_file.read().rstrip('\n')]
...    print(some_list)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'some_file' is not defined
```

Comment: `some_file.txt` as identifier -- ?

Comment: `print(some_string)` will also fail since `some_string` is not defined.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: `some_file` is the identifier and `some_file.txt` is the file to be opened

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open() in Python does not create a file if it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967194/open-in-python-does-not-create-a-file-if-it-doesnt-exist)

Comment: @david, well, that's wrong attempt

Comment: I forgot the quotation marks around `some_file.txt` (see answer). Or is there something else wrong?

Comment: @gregory: [open() in Python does not create a file if it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967194/open-in-python-does-not-create-a-file-if-it-doesnt-exist) deals with a different issue

Comment: @david there are bunch of examples showing quotes around the file one wishes to open to read or write in the topic I cited. Proper basic syntax is better covered there.   This question should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is looking for an object called `some_file` instead of a path string.

Replace `some_file.txt` with `'some_file.txt'`