# pdf file path not found

Tags: python, pdf

(I am using Windows 10, PyCharm)

I am running the following script in the console:

```
pdfFileObj = open(samplepdf.pdf, 'rb')
```

This is the result:

```
NameError: name 'samplepdf' is not defined
```

I checked and made sure that the pdf file is within the project folder that I am operating out of on PyCharm.

I also tried running the same script with the direct path to the file:

```
pdfFileObj = open(C:\Users\Rolex\PycharmProjects\pdf\samplepdf.pdf, 'rb')
```

and received the same result:

```
NameError: name 'samplepdf' is not defined
```

Comment: you need to make it a string, ie add double quotes around sample.pdf like `"sample.pdf"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does using open(filename) fail with "filename not defined"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134908/why-does-using-openfilename-fail-with-filename-not-defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround you filename with quotation marks

```
pdfFileObj = open('samplepdf.pdf', 'rb')
```

Whenever you get a '<> not defined', it means that python is treating <> as a variable. In this case, you do not have a variable called `samplepdf`. The error messages should help you diagnose your issues.

Comment: I cant believe it was really that simple. I am laughing at myself now. Thank you!