# open() does not create new file. FileNotFoundError occurs instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement

I would like to create a text file in the same directory with my python file, but instead, I get FileNotFounfError. I thought that if the file doesn't exist, open() should create a new file.

My python file:

```py
with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("Test")
```

But I receive the following message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/POPOVA/Desktop/Programming/Algs/Stack Overflow/myAns.py", line 1, in <module>
    with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
```

To:

```
with open("test.txt", "w+") as f:
```

You might want to read [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967194/open-in-python-does-not-create-a-file-if-it-doesnt-exist) as well. Splecially this comment:

> The problem is the directory. Either the script lacks the permissions to create a file in that directory, or the directory simply doesn't exist. open('myfile.dat', 'w') is then enough