# Permissions Error and No such file or Directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-permissions

```
if not os.path.exists('/var/log/'):
    os.makedirs('/var/log/')
print(log_filepath)
os.chmod(log_filepath, stat.S_IWOTH)

f_log_in = open(log_filepath, "a")
```

Without the chmod command, it will throw an error saying permission denied for the f_log_in file open command.

```
    f_log_in = open(log_filepath, "a")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/s3_sync.log'
```

When I include the os.chmod command, it says:

```
   os.chmod(log_filepath, stat.S_IWOTH)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/log/s3_sync.log'
```

Are there any other ways of approaching this?

EDIT: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE, I DELETED THE OTHER ONE.

Comment: Will you please add the output of `ls -l /var/log` and `ls -l /var/log/s3_sync.log` to the question?

Comment: @user17242583 ls -l gives me a huge list. The second one does not exist.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant `ls -ld /var/log`. So I can see the rwx permission string for `/var/log`.

Answer (score 0):

The file indicated in `log_filepath` doesn't exist. Thus, you cannot simply open it, as you do with `open`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2967249/442945) for more info, but you need `w+` or `a+` to also create the file.

The second error you get is because of exactly the message - the file doesn't exist, so you can't change the permissions to write to it.

Now, you might *still* have a problem if you are not executing the program as a user with sufficient permissions to access `/var/log` (or wherever `log_filepath` points to). You have to run as a user with sufficient permission - there is no way around that, either by running as a user with that permission or by changing the permissions of the directory itself so that the user you are executing as would have sufficient permission.

Comment: Thank you. I thought `open` created a file if it is not there?

Comment: @mjmr That is true if you use the `a+` or `w+`, but not if you use simply `a` or `w` as the flag you pass to `open`.