# Appending CSV file with API data in a while loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a `with` statement to write and append a CSV file. The `with` is being used in conjunction with a `while` loop that reads data and headers from a paginated API.

As you might see, I haven't worked out how to incorporate the `with` and `while` to achieve this.

I'm using a defined function to return the data. The API uses OAuth2. My account has multiple locations to download from (hence the `location_id` col):

```
def fetch_data_for_location(oauth_session, location_id, page=None, start_time=None, end_time=None):
    # get data from first location returned
    dataurl = "my url that I can't share"
    params = {}
    headers = {}

    # Page is added to the header of the request
    if page is not None:
        headers['start-page'] = page

    # Time filters are added to the query parameters of the request
    if start_time is not None:
        params['start-time'] = start_time

    if end_time is not None:
        params['end-time'] = end_time

    response = oauth_session.get(dataurl, params=params, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    response_headers = response.headers

    return data, response_headers
```

As you will notice, `fetch_data_for_location()` returns two items: `data` and `response_headers`.

Next, I generate the `response_headers` for my chosen location by specifying `[1]` after the function.

The `while` loop checks the headers (`data_headers`) for the header `'next-page'` and continues to read the data until there is no header called `'next-page'`.

Right now I've just set it up so the data will print when they are found.

```
#get response headers
data_headers = fetch_data_for_location(oauth, location1, start_time=0, end_time=None)[1]


#get all data and write to csv
    while data_headers["next-page"] is not None:
        print(fetch_data_for_location(oauth, location1, page=data_headers["next-page"], start_time=0, end_time=None)[0])
        data_headers = fetch_data_for_location(oauth, location1, page=data_headers["next-page"], start_time=0, end_time=None)[1]
```

I would like to append a CSV file with data from this `while` loop. I thought something like this would work:

```
with open('results.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
```

But, I don't know how to reference that in my `while` loop.

The last thing I should mention is that the data are a `dict` object and have a format like this:

```
{'locationId': 6544992693911552, 'parameters': 
[{'parameterId': 'Pressure', 'unitId': 'Unspecified', 'customParameter': True, 'readings': 
[{'timestamp': 1627044780, 'value': 0.09}, {'timestamp': 1627044840, 'value': 0.09}
```

The timestamps continue like that until the next parameter.

Comment: you can use python's unpacking feature `data, headers = fetch_data_for_location(oauth, location1, start_time=0, end_time=1653645628)`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how your response.json() looks like, this is just an example:

```
#get response headers
data, response_headers = fetch_data_for_location(oauth, location1, start_time=0, end_time=1653645628)

#get all data and write to csv
with open('results.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    while response_headers["next-page"] is not None:
        csvfile.write(f"{data['value1']},{data['value2']}")
        data, response_headers = fetch_data_for_location(oauth, location1, page=response_headers["next-page"], start_time=0, end_time=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

To write/append data to CSV file assuming `print(fetch_data_for_location(oauth, location1, page=data_headers["next-page"], start_time=0, end_time=None)[0])` is what you want to write into a CSV file, try below

```
#get response headers
data_headers = fetch_data_for_location(oauth, location1, start_time=0, end_time=None)[1]


#get all data and write to csv
    while data_headers["next-page"] is not None:
        with open('results.csv', 'w+', encoding='UTF8') as csvfile:
           #assuming data_to_write is going to be a dict and key1, key2 are one of the keys
           data_to_write = fetch_data_for_location(oauth, location1, page=data_headers["next-page"], start_time=0, end_time=None)[0]
           csvfile.write(f'{data_to_write["key1"]},{data_to_write["key2"]}')
        data_headers = fetch_data_for_location(oauth, location1, page=data_headers["next-page"], start_time=0, end_time=None)[1]
```

The `w+` is key here as it appends data if the file already exists, otherwise creates it. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967194/open-in-python-does-not-create-a-file-if-it-doesnt-exist)

You can use python's unpacking feature to avoid any additional call to fetch data. Something like below to fetch `data` and `headers` in one go.

```
data, headers = fetch_data_for_location(oauth, location1, start_time=0, end_time=1653645628)
```

Comment: Hi! This seems to work if I use json.dumps() after csvfile.write(). The script takes a while to execute which seemed like a good sign but then I get an error telling me KeyError: "x-isi-next-page". Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Can you post a sample response? You have to extract necessary data from the response and write it as comma separated values

Comment: @obrunt you can use python's `csv` library to ease the csv file generation