# Pandas dataframe to csv on different computers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I created a Python script that creates some pandas dataframes and turn them into csv files.
From my understanding, using .to_csv('file_name.csv') will create locally, in the same folder that contains the Python script, a file called 'file_name.csv'.

Now I gave this same script to a colleague, and asked him to run it. The dataframe is created the same way, and turned into a csv file. But further down, I call this file with the command :

```
with open('empty_list.csv', "rb") as empty_data:
    .................
```

In my computer, that command works fine and it opens it.
In my colleague's computer, this line raises an error "empty_list.csv is not found". And the file has not been created in the folder.

Does anyone know why ?

Comment: May be your colleague should post this question.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967194/open-in-python-does-not-create-a-file-if-it-doesnt-exist

Comment: What are the outputs for `os.getcwd()`? Both for you and your friend.