# Checking for writability in python

Tags: python, file

In Python, I know there is a way of checking whether a directory is writable, but is there a way of checking whether a particular *file* would be writable without actually trying to open it (because that is due to be done in another part of the program and if that part doesn't execute, I don't want the file hanging around)? Currently, I am using a kludgy way of doing this:

```
f = open(stFile, "w")
if not f:
    print('Cannot open' , stFile, ' for writing.')
else:
    f.close()
    os.path.remove(stFile)
```

Is there a better way?  Thanks!
--Sarge

Comment: Specifying an O/S tag would be helpful here. You're getting answers specific to operating systems.

Comment: There are several things that could make a file not writable. You don't want to handle all of them. So, just open the file and handle an potential expection

Comment: Does this answer your question, [w+]((https://stackoverflow.com/a/2967249/20851944). If the file is not exist, the file will be created otherwise it will open the existing file and can overwrite maybe. Otherwise you have to list all existing files with os.walk() and check by your own.

Comment: Not really. It is not enough to close the file.  It has to be deleted. Without actually creating a file, seems to me that the best one can do is to check the directory for writability and hope that one will then be able to write the file. Is there otherwise any reason a file would not be writable, other than that there is already a file there with the same name to which one does not have access? I suppose you could check if such a file already exists and if so, check if one has access to it. That seems cumbersome, but perhaps less so than creating the file and then deleting it.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the os' access method (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.access) to check if the operating system can write on your file :

```
import os

os.access(stFile, os.W_OK)  # return True if writable, False otherwise
```

Edit :

If you plan on openning the file in case it's writable, it's better to do it this way - as stated in the note mentionned in the method documentation :

```
try:
    fp = open(stFile, 'w')
except PermissionError:
    # not writable
    ...
else:
    with fp:
        return fp.read()
```

Comment: The OP asked explicitly:  .. without actually trying to open it .., but you open it.

Comment: Read more carefully : "If you plan on opening the file in case it's writable ...".
The first solution remains completely valid and fully addresses its problem.